# ASP.Net Only 1 Form Restriction: Should I be using a webpage for everything?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am forced to use Web Forms in my project, and sadly, Web Forms only allow - If I may - "Strict" Websites to be created.

Whenever you need a Button you need to put it in a form, and then you need another button which has nothing to do with the previous button, and you can't have 2 forms,

And the idea of putting a DIV that fires a server side (C#) method is kind of difficult, okay it may be easy but all I have found are "tricks", not an "official" clean way.

So I have this idea of making a **webpage** for each action in my websites.

**For Example:**

Let's say I wanna click on the ARROW that raises the rating of this question, I would put something like this.

**HTML**

```
<a href="Rating.aspx?id=23&upOrDown=up" id="rateUpButton">Rate Up</a>
```

And Some CSS Codes to make it look like a beautiful button...

Okay now this will take me to a page called **Rating.aspx** with 2 parameters, the first parameter is the ID of the question that I would like to raise its rating, and the second parameter is either UP (+rating) or DOWN(-rating).

On the Page Load method of Rating.aspx, I would update the database, then redirect to the question page.

This will work perfectly, BUT, is it a good approach? is it professional? (put in mind that there will be many actions to preform like that...)

Comment: using aspx pages makes only sense when you use the code-behind options (C#, VB.NET). If you want to do e everything clientside then you can just use a htm-page, what also works without problems in the .NET environment.

Answer (score 0):

With ASP.NET you better use server controls. Better way of implementing that is using  or , that actually renders your anchor tag. But you can attach OnClick event handler to this control (link button) so after clicking there would be automatic POST to server. The same page cycle for the current page will take place (this is called PostBack) and your attached event handler will fire, where you can actually make changes to the database. So you don't even need to create any other pages for tasks like this. Every server control has specific set of events like OnClick for buttons or OnSelectedIndexChanged for dropdown lists. You can even create your own controls or derive from existing ones and create your own events.

Take a look on following links for more information:

[Button Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx)

[Event Handling in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)